# Trying to set pandas column with 2D data

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm looking to generate some sample data with NumPy to test a CNN model but NumPy returns  `Exception: Data must be 1-dimensional`. The code is as follows:

```
size = 10000 
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['input1', 'input2', 'label'])
df['input1'] = np.random.randint(0, 100, (85, 1024))
df['input2'] = np.random.randint(0, 100, (32, 20, 26, 8))
df['label'] = np.random.randint(1, 10, (1))

df.to_csv('sample_data.csv')
```

Here, I am trying to generate a 85 by 1024 matrix as `input 1`, a 32 by 20 by 26 by 8 tensor as `input 2`, and a number as a label. I have tried both `np.random.ranint(0, 100, size=(85, 1024))` and `np.random.ranint(0, 100, (85, 1024))`. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: As the error says, you are trying to set a pandas series with a 2D data. You can't do that. `df['input']` corresponds to a column. A column can only be one-dimensional. If you need to save your data into a file, save it as a binary file using `np.save` or as a pickle or something similar. It's not very convenient to use pandas here imo.

Comment: @Ananda, what would you recommend for what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to answer your question:
*what would you recommend for what I'm trying to do?*

Answer:
when I have a data structure that is 1D or 2D, I use **pandas + to_csv()**.
when I have a data structure more complex than that, I use **numpy + pickle**.

here I append an example:

```
import numpy as np
import pickle
np.random.seed(42)

# create test data
size_test = 10000
input1, input2, labels = [], [], []
for i in range(size_test):
    input1.append(np.random.randint(0, 100, (85, 1024)))
    input2.append(np.random.randint(0, 100, (32, 20, 26, 8)))
    labels.append(np.random.randint(1, 10, 1))

# store test data on disk
test_objects = (input1, input2, labels)
pickle.dump(test_objects, open("test_objects.pkl", "wb"))

# read test data from file
x1, x2, y = pickle.load(open("test_objects.pkl", "rb"))
for i in range(len(x1)):
    print(x1[i], x2[i], y[I])
```

Update:
Question: 'what if I have insufficient ram? can I store the file on disk'.
Answer: you can split the file in chunks of reduced size and store them on disk.

Example:

```
import os
import pickle
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(42)

# create folder to store test files
dir_path = "test_files"
os.makedirs(dir_path, exist_ok=True)

# create test data
size_test = 10000
chunks = 10
size_chunk = int(size_test / chunks)
for chunk in range(chunks):
    # create one test chunk
    input1, input2, labels = [], [], []
    for i in range(size_chunk):
        input1.append(np.random.randint(0, 100, (85, 1024)))
        input2.append(np.random.randint(0, 100, (32, 20, 26, 8)))
        labels.append(np.random.randint(1, 10, 1))
    # store chunk on disk
    test_objects = (input1, input2, labels)
    chunk_path = os.path.join(dir_path, "{}_test_chunk.pkl".format(chunk))
    print("storing test file {} in {}".format(chunk, chunk_path))
    pickle.dump(test_objects, open(chunk_path, "wb"))
print('\n')

# read all chunks
test_files = os.listdir(dir_path)
x1, x2, y = [], [], []
for i, file in enumerate(sorted(test_files)):
    test_file_path = os.path.join(dir_path, file)
    print("reading test file {} from {}".format(i, test_file_path))
    x1_i, x2_i, y_i = pickle.load(open(test_file_path, "rb"))
    x1.append(x1_i)
    x2.append(x2_i)
    y.append(y_i)

# merge the chunks into a unique array ( if you really need to )
x1_array = np.concatenate(x1)
x2_array = np.concatenate(x2)
y_array = np.concatenate(y)
```

Comment: where would I pass the argument to generate 10,000 samples?

Comment: The easiest way is to append 10.000 elements to a list using a loop.
Then, use a second loop to read them. I edited the answer, including this feature.

Comment: thanks for your answer. It was really helpful. I've been trying to do this but the script seems to overflow the RAM. From what I understand, this script will create the file in RAM then save it to the disc drive. Is it possible to adapt this code to write to write the file to the disc drive directly?

Comment: Not really. But the test object can be split in chunks and stored as multiple files. Then you can load the files and merge them. I updated the answer with an example.